# How can I make use of the labels subdivision in a Deep Learning Image classification?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, labels

I want to solve an image classification problem. I want to recognize `cats` and `dogs`. However my labels are more detailed than this - they contain information about the dog/cat `breed`.
 In other words I want to classify images into A and B, but for each photo I know labels such as A.1, A.2, B.1, B.2.

If I simply cast the labels into A and B I lose some of the expertise I have. 
I can try to classify into detailed labels first and then cast the results.

However I don't want my neural network to focus on distinguishing between particular sublabels.

Are there any rules of a thumb on it? Any name for such a problem I don't know?